# Spirit Qi sequence parsing issues

Tags: c++, parsing, boost, boost-spirit, regex-lookarounds

I have some issues with parser writing with Spirit::Qi 2.4.
I have a series of key-value pairs to parse in following format `<key name>=<value>`.

*Key name* can be `[a-zA-Z0-9]` and is always followed by `=` sign with no white-space between *key name* and `=` sign. *Key name* is also always preceded by at least one space.

*Value* can be almost any C expression (spaces are possible as well), with the exception of the expressions containing `=` char and code blocks `{ }`.

At the end of the sequence of the key value pairs there's a `{` sign.

I struggle a lot with writing parser for this expression. Since the key name always is preceded by at least one space and followed by `=` and contains no spaces I defined it as

```
  KeyName %= [+char_("a-zA-Z0-9_") >> lit("=")] ;
```

Value can be almost anything, but it can not contain `=` nor `{` chars, so I defined it as:

```
  Value %=  +(char_ - char_("{=")) ;
```

I thought about using look-ahead's like this to catch the value:

```
ValueExpression 
    %= ( 
      Value  
      >> *space 
      >> &(KeyName | lit("{"))
    )
    ;
```

But it won't work, for some reason (seems like the `ValueExpression` greedily goes up to the `=` sign and "doesn't know" what to do from there). I have limited knowledge of LL parsers, so I'm not really sure what's cooking here. Is there any other way I could tackle this kind of sequence?

Here's example series:

```
EXP1=FunctionCall(A, B, C) TEST="Example String" \
AnotherArg=__FILENAME__ - 'BlahBlah' EXP2= a+ b+* {
```

**Additional info:** since this is a part of a much larger grammar I can't really solve this problem any other way than by a Spirit.Qi parser (like splitting by '=' and doing some custom parsing or something similar).

**Edit:**

I've created minimum working example here: http://ideone.com/kgYD8
(compiled under VS 2012 with boost 1.50, but should be fine on older setups as well).

Comment: What if you change +(char_-char_("{=")) to +~char_("{=") ?

Comment: I could give you a run down of things that struck me as odd in your sample code, but I fear it may not be relevant to your _real code_ (as this is minimized). If you care, I can answer more questions you may have, [beyond the answer I posted](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11353205/85371), if you post a new question/your real code.

Comment: Sure, please share your insights!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest you have a look at the article [Parsing a List of Key-Value Pairs Using Spirit.Qi](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/qi-example/parsing-a-list-of-key-value-pairs-using-spirit-qi/).

I've *greatly* simplified your code, while

- adding attribute handling
- removing phoenix semantic actions
- debugging of rules

Here it is, without further ado:

```
#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG

#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <map>

namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;
namespace fusion = boost::fusion;

typedef std::map<std::string, std::string> data_t;

template <typename It, typename Skipper>
struct grammar : qi::grammar<It, data_t(), Skipper>
{
    grammar() : grammar::base_type(Sequence)
    {
        using namespace qi;

        KeyName  = +char_("a-zA-Z0-9_") >> '=';
        Value    = qi::no_skip [+(~char_("={") - KeyName)];
        Sequence = +(KeyName > Value);

        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(KeyName);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(Value);
        BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODE(Sequence);
    }
  private:
    qi::rule<It, data_t(), Skipper>      Sequence;
    qi::rule<It, std::string()>          KeyName; // no skipper, removes need for qi::lexeme
    qi::rule<It, std::string(), Skipper> Value;
};

template <typename Iterator>
data_t parse (Iterator begin, Iterator end)
{
    grammar<Iterator, qi::space_type> p;

    data_t data;

    if (qi::phrase_parse(begin, end, p, qi::space, data)) {
        std::cout << "parse ok\n";
        if (begin!=end) {
            std::cout << "remaining: " << std::string(begin,end) << '\n';
        }
    } else {
        std::cout << "failed: " << std::string(begin,end) << '\n';
    }

    return data;
}

int main ()
{
    std::string test(" ARG=Test still in first ARG ARG2=Zombie cat EXP2=FunctionCall(A, B C) {" );
    auto data = parse(test.begin(), test.end());

    for (auto& e : data)
        std::cout << e.first << "=" << e.second << '\n';
}
```

Output will be:

```
parse ok
remaining: {
ARG=Test still in first ARG 
ARG2=Zombie cat 
EXP2=FunctionCall(A, B C)
```

If you really wanted '{' to be part of the last value, change this line:

```
Value    = qi::no_skip [+(char_ - KeyName)];
```

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you. I didn't know about rule debugging and still am a bit confused about skippers. As much as I love the idea of Spirit, I find the lack of proper all-in-one-place documentation (everything seems to be spread around in hundreds of those articles), best-practices, and more elaborate examples makes it really hard to get it right. I didn't know you can debug rules like this, also I like how the compile time of your sample is 1/5th of mine's.

Comment: @kurczak Spirit is not a _simple_ library: it favours power and flexibility, sacrificing simplicity. To me, the documentation is awesome. What you seem to be looking for, is experience. With a non-simple framework like this, the only way to get it is is: repeated application. The articles/samples/tests are a nice source of _inspiration_ in case you lack the right toy projects.